# Qbs StaticLibrary on MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, qt, static-libraries, qbs

I try to move an existing project from qmake to qbs, everything works fine so far but i can't link to google test static library in that project on MacOS while on windows it works fine.

On MacOS i get `:-1: error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`

[GitHub repo of the project](https://github.com/emKaroly/QbsTest)

googletest.qbs:

```
import qbs

StaticLibrary {
    name: "GoogleTest"
    files: [
        "googletest/googletest/src/gtest-all.cc",
        "googletest/googlemock/src/gmock-all.cc"
    ]

    cpp.includePaths: [
        "googletest/googletest/include",
        "googletest/googlemock/include",
        "googletest/googletest",
        "googletest/googlemock"
    ]

    Depends { name: "cpp" }
    Export {
        Depends { name: "cpp" }
        cpp.includePaths: [
            "googletest/googletest/include",
            "googletest/googlemock/include"
        ]
    }
}
```

test.qbs:

```
import qbs

QtApplication {
    name: "Test"
    targetName: "Test"

    Depends { name: "Qt"; submodules: ["core","testlib"]; versionAtLeast: "5.6" }
    Depends { name: "GoogleTest"}

    cpp.cxxLanguageVersion: "c++11"
    consoleApplication: true

    files: [
        "QtTypePrinters.h",
        "main.cpp",
        "QStringTest.cpp"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the following properties in your static library product:

```
cpp.cxxLanguageVersion: "c++11"
cpp.cxxStandardLibrary: "libc++"
cpp.minimumMacosVersion: "10.7" // or higher
```

By default, Qbs simply lets the compiler infer the defaults. gtest happens to require C++11 and libc++, which in turn is only supported by Apple on macOS 10.7 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that's the entire error message from the linker? Surely the actual missing symbol(s) are mentioned as well?

Comment: if i link to that library by cpp.libraryPaths and cpp.staticLibrariesit works but that is not what i want.

Comment: Please provide the full error message so that we can properly diagnose the issue.

Comment: Perhaps a standard library compatibility issue? You haven't pasted the whole compile output, so we cannot say for sure, but please try adding 'cpp.cxxLanguageVersion: "c++11"' to your static library also.

Comment: Please take a look at the github repository of the project

Comment: It appears that qbs thinks your system does not support libc++. Try setting cpp.cxxStandardLibrary to "libc++".

Comment: @emKaroly Lastly, set `cpp.minimumMacosVersion: "10.7"` (or a later version).

Comment: @JakePetroules Solved  That was the problem. If you want, you can write it as answer. Can you tell me why was this necessary?